# Accept zip file using postman

Tags: .net-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created api project in .Net Core application. I have also created Method to accept `HttpRequestMessage` as parameter. Now I am trying to call my api method using `Postman` with including file as body parameter, but my api method is not calling.

Here is code

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostFiles()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Request;

        return result;
    }}
```

Here is `Postman` request data

```
POST /api/values/PostFiles HTTP/1.1
```

Host: localhost:64226
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 6adcc652-a4ab-3714-cc5e-770bd214ac7a

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename=""
Content-Type:

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--

Here is the screen shot of my api call using postman.

[image]

Request body with file as parameter

[image]

Is there anything that I am missing?

Can you please help me out to call my web api with accepting file as parameter using Postman?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's a problem with your route. Try this :

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [Route("api/values/postfiles")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostFiles()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        var files = Request.Form.Files;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then try accessing the API at http://localhost:yourport/api/values/postfiles .

replace "yourport" in your port no.

You'll get the file in "fileStream" if the file is available.

Comment: [RoutePrefix("api") attribute missing directive or assembly.. How can I get that in .Net Core api project ?

Also the 'HttpContext.Current.Request.Files' for that which namespace to refer ?

  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, there is indeed no RoutePrefixAttribute in core. So, applying a [Route] attribute on a controller will now act as a route prefix. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Also , use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http for HttpContext.

Comment: Still its not working. Not able to call post method using Postman.

Comment: Now its calling my method but not able to travers HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath ?  How can I use HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath in .Net Core applicaiton ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135173/discussion-between-jose-francis-and-herin).

Answer (score 0):

In an ASP.NET Core application use IHostingEnvironment. Then you can call ContentRootPath and WebRootPath